# Listview doesn't display correct row details when clicked

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a listview linked to a sqlite database. I have 3 items in the database, but everytime I click on the second and third value it gives me the same result as the very first value in the record set. How do I move through subsequent items in the recordset? Here is the code:

```
            DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    //Get cursor for list items
    cursor = db.getAllChannels();


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {


            //String cText = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            //retrieve database values
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_STATIONURL)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the adapter is already populated using a cursor, you should refrain from acquiring data using the cursor fed to the adapter. Instead use `getItem(int position)` which should return a cursor that is already pointed to the correct item in your list. Your code would then look like this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {

            //retrieve database values
            Cursor tempCursor = getItem(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tempCursor.getString(tempCursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_STATIONURL)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });
```

You can go a step further and override your CursorAdapter's `getItem(position)` so that it returns a `Data`* object wherein you just need to `getKeyStationUrl()`* to get the value that you need.